# shutil.move() behaves strangely with locked file in Windows

Tags: python-3.x

I've found that if I try to move a file in windows that is locked, for example a document open in Word, that shutil.move() will make a copy in the destination folder, and then throw an exception.  I want it to simply throw an expection, my application should not move locked files.

Here is the code:

```
for file in source_non_text_files:
    print('Unrecognized file ['+str(file)+'] moved to error folder')
    try:
        shutil.move(str(file),str(error_path))
    except IOError as err:
        print('Something went wrong'+str(err))
```

It works as expected for unlocked files.  But for locked files it makes a copy and then throws the following exception:

[WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'source_dir\foobar.docx'

Is there any way to make it work the way I want short of removing the copy in the exception block?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're hitting a Sharing Violation error.  I'd recommend using the win32file.MoveFile function instead.  According to the docs it should appropriately raise an exception rather than creating a copy and prior to failing.

Here is some test case code I wrote a long time ago, It's not a replacement for your function, just code that I've wrote to test a file system implementation (based on NTFS behavior)

```
try:
    self.log.info("Testing that moving an open file throws a Sharing Violation)
    self.log.info("Creating file: %s" % source)
    fd = win_create.create_file(source)
    self.test_files.append(source)
    self.log.info("Attempting to move open file -- Should fail")
    try:
        win32file.MoveFile(source, target)
        self.test_files.append(target)
        raise RuntimeError("MoveFile should have failed!!")
    except win32file.error as e:
        if e.winerror is 32:  # SHARE VIOLATION
            self.log.info("Caught correct exception: %s: %s"
                          % (e.winerror, e.strerror))
            self.passed = True
        else:
            raise
except:
    self.log.error("The following exception was raised: %s"
                   % traceback.format_exc())
```

Otherwise if you require cross platform compatibility, you can use os.rename which also throws an error immediately. it'll probably require some os.name conditionals to make sure your code behaves correctly in this case.  Also if you are copying across file systems there may be some additional work to get around cross-device errors. Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect!  Took a couple of other tweaks to the paths and exception and it works as expected:    `for file in source_non_text_files:
        print('Unrecognized file ['+str(file)+'] moved to error folder')
        try:
            win32file.MoveFile(str(file),str(error_path.joinpath(file.name)))
        except win32file.error as err:
            print('Something went wrong: '+str(err))`